# PS4 in Fallout 4 I often get clouds in my vision

Tags: ps4, fallout

It says my image is too big. I’ve noticed it starts small but grows to cover 80% of my view, and then it will go away for a while. Sleeping seems to help for some time. It always seems to happen when I’m confronting an enemy. If I circle around I can put clouds behind me. If enemies go to that side I’m in trouble. At first I thought it was mole rat disease from the vault where you get the antidote but I gave it all to save the boy.

Comment: This website says your image is too big? Please find a way to resize it (you can find a lot of tools that do this in your browser, just search for "image resize"), because that would help your question a lot.

Comment: Do you have survival mode enabled?

Comment: Yes I don’t know how to disable on ps4

Comment: Last night I noticed it helps for a while if I take off the jet pack then put it back on.